# Is there some trick to how (or who) to sacrifice in Boethiah's Calling?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sacrifice someone in Boethiah’s Calling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38746/how-to-sacrifice-someone-in-boethiahs-calling)

So, I sacrificed someone I beat in a brawl, but nothing happend. The pillar looms active with re magical dome and all but nothing went down. I feel like I'm missing something. Does it have to be a certain person or is there some other trick that's required?

Comment: need more information

Answer (score 2):

You have to get a follower, like a mercenary from a tavern or somebody, lead them there and then command them to touch the pillar. You then sacrifice them for Boethiah, who will then send you on another quest so you can receive your ebony mail.

Answer (score 0):

To sacrifice somebody, talk to them and direct them to touch the pillar. They will be sucked in and restrained, then you can kill them to make a sacrifice. Boethiah will possess the corpse and talk to you. If it doesn't, then you've hit a bug and should reload to an earlier save and try again.