# How to get followers to respond to orders?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whenever I get followers I can't get them to do anything. When I talk to them and get them to do something like search a corpse or wait here, they won't do it.  They just stand there. This makes it so I can't complete the Boethiah's calling quest. This is happening on both of my characters.  (I use an Xbox if that helps.)

Comment: Have you looked at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38746/how-to-sacrifice-someone-in-boethiahs-calling ?  It suggests several possible issues.  You might also consider telling us what followers you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was I changed the controls so I jump with b and activate with a. So I changed it back and it worked